# Не работает "ctrl" "c", "ctrl" "v", на русском языке. python, pyautogui

Tags: python, pyautogui

Например, хочу я копировать русский текст, а pyautogui почему то не понимает русского языка и не копирует русское слово, как исправить?

Comment: Для начала проверить, не в русской ли раскладке Ctrl-C и Ctrl-v делается. Надо в английской.

Comment: @Сергей Спасибо, очень благодарен.